# Allow links with preg-replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this so far :

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/!?\" \' :,.;><_ ]/", "", 
html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES));
```

It works well, if I use other string a part from links 
.How do i accept 
`<script></script> <iframe> <a href=""></a> http:// https://` ?

Comment: Are you trying to allow any urls? What is the objective here?

Comment: @Idealcastle yes i would like all tags listed above and urls allowed for the purposes of display.

Answer (score 0):

I have done many projects with RegEx in the past, here is a few of my queries.

**Match "Every" link on a page.**

```
$links = preg_match_all('#(?:<a\s+.*?href=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]\s*?.*?>((?:\s*(?!<\s*\/\s*a\s*>).\s*)*)<\s*\/\s*a\s*>)#i',$html,$patterns);

 // $patterns[0] (array) will give you the full tag <a herf="" ...etc
 // $patterns[1] (array) will give you the urls
```

You should `print_r($patterns)` to be sure what the actual arrays look like and how you want to use them.

**To match `<script>` tags** (this actually finds full javascript blocks, which may not be exactly what you're asking), however you can modify the code some.

```
preg_match_all("#<\s*script[^>]*[^/]>(.*?)<\s*/\s*script\s*>#i",$html,$scripts);
```

**To match `<iframe>`** you can use this function (matches "every" iframe tag within html)

```
function html_iframe_tags($str) 
{
    $iframes = array();
    $iframeSearch = preg_match_all('#(?:<iframe[^>]*)(?:(?:/>)|(?:>.*?</\s*iframe>))#i', $str, $rawiframes);
    if (count($rawiframes[0])<1) return false;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($rawiframes[0]); $i++)
    {
        $iframes[$i]['tag'] = $rawiframes[0][$i];

        preg_match_all('/src="([^"]*)"/i',$iframes[$i]['tag'], $iframesrc);
        $iframes[$i]['src'] = (isset($iframesrc[1][0]) ? $iframesrc[1][0] : '');

        preg_match_all('/\swidth="([^"]*)"/i',$iframes[$i]['tag'], $iframewidth);
        $iframes[$i]['width'] = (isset($iframewidth[1][0]) ? $iframewidth[1][0] : '');

        preg_match_all('/\sheight="([^"]*)"/i',$iframes[$i]['tag'], $iframeheight);
        $iframes[$i]['height'] = (isset($iframeheight[1][0]) ? $iframeheight[1][0] : '');
    }

    return $iframes;
 }
```

Then `print_r()` the results and see how the array looks for your exact usage, this function actually determines more than your use such as width/height etc. But also includes the `src` of which you are looking for.

Hopefully this stuff can give you direction for your project.

Here is a website that has some reference to regex in html
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/parse-links/